# Show div contents on click on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, drop-down-menu

I am really stuck on this. I have a dropdown menu called "Example" that contains 2 submenus "submenu1" and "submenu2". When either of the 2 is clicked, it will contain an image thumb which will be displayed in lightbox style. But as of now both thumbs are displayed and this is not what I want because the final web page will contain hundreds of images. Is there a way to make the images appear only when one sub-menu is clicked, according to the code below. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>        
<!-- Portfolio Projects -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <!-- Filter -->
            <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li class="type-work">CATEGORIES</li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" 
     >BAPTISM
                    <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="selected">BOY CLOTHING</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-
        value=".boy" tabindex="-1">Clothing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">GIRL CLOTHING</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-  
                value=".girl" tabindex="-1">Clothing</a></li>
</ul>
                    </li>
                    </ul>


                    </li>

</ul>
  </li>
        </nav>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         

                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Filter -->
        </div>

        <div class="span9">
            <div class="row">
                <section id="projects">
                    <ul id="thumbs">

                        <!-- gallery starts here -->

                       <li class="item-thumbs span3 boy"><!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled    
                            - Title - Full Image -->
<a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="boy" 
     title="" href="_include/img/work/full/boy_clothing.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>

                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/boy_clothing.jpg" alt="">
                       </li>
                       <li class="item-thumbs span3 girl">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="girl"     
                            title="" href="_include/img/work/full/girl_clothing.jpg">   
<span class="overlay-img"></span>

                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                  <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/girl_clothing.jpg" 
alt="">           
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Portfolio Projects -->




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe can you show us some CSS

Comment: .work-nav #filters {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
    }

    .work-nav #filters li {
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
    }

    .work-nav #filters li a {
 color: #515151;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: block;
    }

    .work-nav #filters li a:hover {
 color: #5892A8;
    }
 
    .work-nav #filters li a.selected {
 color: #5892A8;
    }

    #thumbs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
    }

Comment: #thumbs li {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.item-thumbs {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.item-thumbs a + img {
 width: 100%; 
}

Comment: .item-thumbs .hover-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 -webkit-transition: all 450ms ease-out 0s; 
    -moz-transition: all 450ms ease-out 0s;
   -o-transition: all 450ms ease-out 0s;
      transition: all 450ms ease-out 0s;

Comment: -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5,0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5,0.5);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5,0.5);
   -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5,0.5);
   transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5,0.5); 
}

Comment: .item-thumbs:hover .hover-wrap,
.item-thumbs.active .hover-wrap {
 opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1,1);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1,1);
-ms-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1,1);
-o-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1,1);
transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1,1);
}

Comment: you can edit your original post :)

Comment: Oh sorry, it;s the first time I am posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW I can't believe I found the solution after so many days by adding just a simple word. Didn't have to mess with javascript at all. Actually in the **external .js** file of the website I was told by a code developer to add the following: **filter: '.foobar'**                                                                          See the final result below                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       `$container.isotope({
          // options
          animationEngine: 'best-available',
          itemSelector : '.item-thumbs',
          filter: '.foobar',
          layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
I try and keep the logic simple, then you can just use something similar on your site :)

*(Please S.O.  Correct me if I am wrong here!)*

**CSS:**

*Give your submenus an ID*

**JavaScript:**

```
// 2 event listeners that will run a function when the submenu is clicked:

var sub_menu_1 = document.getElementById( "submenu1" );
sub_menu_1.addEventListener("click", DISPLAY_menu_1 , false);

var sub_menu_2 = document.getElementById( "submenu2" );
sub_menu_2.addEventListener("click", DISPLAY_menu_1 , false);

function DISPLAY_menu_1 () {
   // Do whatever CSS you need here, I simply make the entire DIV 'visible':
   sub_menu_1.style.visibility = 'visible';
   // For good measures, lets make submenu2 'invisible':
   sub_menu_2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function DISPLAY_menu_2 () {
   // Same in Reverse
   sub_menu_2.style.visibility = 'visible';

   sub_menu_1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

**EDIT:**

Whew! This took a while.. Sorry about that!

Check out this example:
I basically made 3 versions for you to try out.

Simply click the **Edit this Pen** button to check the code!

[Example](http://cdpn.io/yItqv)

Comment: I can't seem to find the ID name of the sumenus you provided in the java code though. Could you please rename the html code with the proper classes and IDs so that I have a better picture, because I am kinda lost.

Comment: That's because you haven't added them. This is an example. You should consider doing some basic tutorials. Try to google: Codeacademy

Comment: Also. It's JavaScript. Not Java. Totally different languages

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will definitely check it out. I just need to be sure about the ID in the javascript you provided. Is it this?          getElementById("submenu1" ) and this for the other one,  getElementById( "submenu2" ).

Comment: Try a simpler example to get you going. I will add it to my answer in a moment

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I will keep them in mind for future projects. They will be useful for sure.